# Using Path and Paths in Java

Tags: java, path

The interaction between Path and Paths seems simple enough. You get a Path object using Paths' `get()` method. You can then use Path's methods:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\directory\\filename.txt");
p.getFilename();
p.getRoot();
p.getParent();
etc...
```

What's confusing me is the fact that the Java documentation describes Path as being an interface. Normally speaking, an interface is just a collection of method signatures which you need to implement in any class which declares that it uses it via the `implements` keyword.

However, in the case of Path, there's no 'implements' keyword used and you don't implement the methods. They're already predefined.

I've obviously got the wrong end of the stick somewhere. Can someone please explain what I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is OOP substituion principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

```
If S is a T, then references to T can be changed to references to S
```

In our case it means that Paths can return an instance of any class which implements Path. If I print the actual class name

```
System.out.println(p.getClass());
```

I'll get

```
class sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath
```

As you can see this is Windows specific Path implementation. Naturally on Linux we would get something different. Using static factory method returning an interface allows this method to change the actual implementation of this interface.

Answer (score 1):

`Path` is an interface. Select the object somewhere in your code and press F4 to get the Type Hierarchy. This will show you the actual implementations. You will see this:

```
Path
- AbstractPath
  - WindowPath
- ZipPath
```

`Paths` is a concrete implementation which provides the service to return a `Path` by `Paths.get(filename)`. The `Paths` class will instantiate one of the concrete implementations which you can see in the Type Hierarchy. It is best practise to return the most generic type which is `Path` here. So your own implementation is independent of the underlying implementation of `Path`, it could be a `WindowPath` or a `ZipPath`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Paths.get("C:\\directory\\filename.txt");
```

Returns the resulting `Path` implemented Object(Based on OS).The Path is obtained by invoking the `getPath()` method of the default `FileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

`Path` is an interface and `Paths.get()` is a factory method for producing concrete implementations.

The exact concrete class returned will depend upon your operating system and filesystem type.